# Not inserting the value in one column in db using yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to `YII`. Problem is that I am having issue s in entering the user record. It is not inserting the complete record in db. skipping last field. Below are my controller and model. It is not inserting the `$heard_about_us` in database.

```
class UsersController extends Karmora
user controller action 
    public function actionSignUp($affusername=null)
    {
        //echo "all is well";exit;
        if(!empty($affusername)){
            $this->VarifyUser($affusername);
            $user_data = Users::model()->getUsersByUserName($affusername);  //getting user information
        }
        else {
            $user_data = '';
        }
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($user_data); exit;


        $this->ticker_news =  NewsTicker::model()->getTickerNews();

        $model=new Users('signup'); //apply rules if user comes directly to signup page

        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($model); exit;

        // uncomment the following code to enable ajax-based validation
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='users-signup-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
        $referrer_data="";
        if(empty($affusername))
        $referrer_data = $model->getUsersByRole("SuperAdmin");
        else{
            $referrer_data = $model->getUsersByUserName($affusername);

            //if invalid affiliate name then redirect to home page
            if(!$referrer_data) {
                $this->redirect($this->base_url.'/home');
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['Users']))
        {   
            $_POST['Users']['optin'] = 0;
            $_POST['Users']['registration_date'] = date('y-m-d h:i:s');
            $_POST['Users']['role'] = "Affiliate";
            $_SESSION['newUser']    =   $_POST['Users'];

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                //assigning referral key to new created user
                $model->referrer = $referrer_data['id'];
                $model->state = $_POST['Users']['state'];
                // $model->subid = uniqid();

                /*
                 $this->displayData($_POST);
                 exit;
                 */

                /*
                 Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
                 require_once('iPayout.php');
                 $config = array(
                 'MerchantGUID' => 'abcdefghi;dks;dfk',
                 'MerchantPassword' => 'password',
                 'eWalletAPIURL' => "https://www.testewallet.com/eWalletWS/ws_adapter.aspx"
                 );

                 $iPayout_obj = new iPayout($config);
                 $response = $iPayout_obj->iPayout_GetUniqueUserName(array('UserName'=>$_POST['Users']['username']));

                 //echo $response;

                 $check_username = json_decode($response);
                 $model->ewallet_username = $check_username->valid_user_name;
                 */

                // Jan 17, 2014, By IK, added new API
                // Import Authorize.Net SDK from vendors
                Yii::import('application.vendors/anet_php_sdk.*');
                require_once('AuthorizeNet.php');

                // If coupon code then
                $trial = false;
                if ($_POST['Users']['token']) {
                    $trial = true;
                }

                /* Authorize.Net test credit card numbers
                 - American Express Test Card: 370000000000002
                 - Discover Test Card: 6011000000000012
                 - Visa Test Card: 4007000000027
                 - Second Visa Test Card: 4012888818888
                 - JCB: 3088000000000017
                 - Diners Club/ Carte Blanche: 38000000000006*/

                // Set the subscription fields.
                $amount = 25;
                $subscription = new AuthorizeNet_Subscription();
                $subscription->name = $_POST['Users']['username']; //Merchant-assigned name for the subscription
                $subscription->intervalLength = "1";
                //$subscription->refId = "willid";
                $subscription->intervalUnit = "months";
                $subscription->startDate = date('Y-m-d'); //(YYYY-MM-DD) "2014-02-12";
                $subscription->totalOccurrences = "9999";
                $subscription->amount = $amount;

                if ($trial) {
                    $subscription->trialOccurrences = "3";
                    $subscription->trialAmount = "0";
                }

                $subscription->creditCardCardNumber = $_POST['Users']["cardNumber"];
                $subscription->creditCardExpirationDate = $_POST['Users']["exp_year"].'-'.$_POST['Users']["exp_month"]; //"2015-10";
                $subscription->creditCardCardCode = $_POST['Users']["cardCode"];
                $subscription->billToFirstName = $_POST['Users']["first_name"];
                $subscription->billToLastName = $_POST['Users']["last_name"];

                // Create the subscription.
                $request = new AuthorizeNetARB(API_LOGIN_NAME, API_TRANSACTION_KEY);
                $response = $request->createSubscription($subscription);
                $isOk = $response->isOk();

                // Payment is successfull and create user account
                if ($isOk) {

                    // Authorize.Net Subscription id
                    $subscription_id = $response->getSubscriptionId();

                    if ($model->save()){

                        /******* Create blog ************/
                        $user_id = yii::app()->db->lastInsertID;
                        Yii::app()->session['username'] =   $_POST['Users']['username'];
                        yii::app()->session['user_id'] = $user_id;
                        yii::app()->session['first_name'] = $_POST['Users']['first_name'];
                        yii::app()->session['email'] = $_POST['Users']['email'];
                        Yii::app()->session['password'] =   $_POST['Users']['password'];
                        $db_user_data = $model->findByPk($user_id);
                        if(!(Users::model()->updateAll(array("status" => "active", "subid" => $subscription_id), "id = $user_id"))) {
                            //echo 'user not updated';
                        }

                        // Jan 17, 2014, Commented by IK, old Authorize.net is replaced by Authorize.Net SDK
                        /*
                         Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
                         require_once('karmora_authorizenet.php');

                         $config = array(
                         'loginname' => '8QqN8Q9p4P',
                         'transactionkey' => '7653C9N3VumpMn26',
                         'host' => "apitest.authorize.net",
                         'path' => "/xml/v1/request.api"
                         );

                         $kauthnet_obj = new karmora_authorizenet($config);
                         $authnet_data['amount'] = '25.0';
                         $authnet_data['refId'] = $db_user_data["subid"];
                         $authnet_data['name'] = $db_user_data["username"]; //Merchant-assigned name for the subscription
                         $authnet_data['length'] = 1;
                         $authnet_data['unit'] = 'months';
                         $authnet_data['startDate'] = date('Y-m-d'); //2013-11-05 (YYYY-MM-DD)
                         $authnet_data['totalOccurrences'] = '9999';
                         //$authnet_data['trialOccurrences'] = 2;
                         //$authnet_data['trialAmount'] = 0;
                         $authnet_data['cardNumber'] = $_POST['Users']["cardNumber"];
                         $authnet_data['expirationDate'] = $_POST['Users']["exp_year"].'-'.$_POST['Users']["exp_month"];
                         $authnet_data['firstName'] = $db_user_data["first_name"];
                         $authnet_data['lastName'] = $db_user_data["last_name"];
                         $con = $kauthnet_obj->setARBContent($authnet_data);
                         //print_r($con);
                         //print_r($kauthnet_obj);
                         $subscription_create = $kauthnet_obj->createARBSubscription();
                         */

                        /*
                            Array
                            (
                            [refId] => 529722f838d54
                            [resultCode] => Ok
                            [code] => I00001
                            [text] => Successful.
                            [subscriptionId] => 1895540
                            )
                         */

                        /******* Authorize.net END **********/

                        /*  Commented by IK, we don't need blog at the moment
                         *  Jan 10, 2014
                         *  Blog creation login is not working at the moment due to some bug
                         */

                        // Create blog
                        //$is_created = $this->CreateBlog($db_user_data);
                        /*if($is_created){
                            //echo 'BLOG CREATED';exit;
                            $this->updatedBlogUserStatus();
                            $this->redirect($this->base_url.'/videos');
                            }
                            else{

                            $subject = "Blog not created for user";
                            $message = "Error while creating a blog for following user<br><br>";
                            $message.="<b>User Detail:</b><br>";
                            $message.="Username: ".$db_user_data['username']."<br>";
                            $message.="Email: ".$db_user_data['email']."<br>";
                            $this->SendKarmoraMail($subject, $message, 'irfan.k@dprodigy.com');
                            //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)
                            }*/
                        /********** end create blog *****************/

                        $Loginmodel=new LoginForm();
                        $LoginFormData['username'] = $_POST['Users']['username'];
                        $LoginFormData['password'] = $_POST['Users']['password'];

                        //print_r($LoginFormData);

                        $Loginmodel->attributes=$LoginFormData;

                        if(!($Loginmodel->validate() && $Loginmodel->login())){
                            //echo 'Login failed';
                            $this->redirect($this->base_url); // Uncomment later
                        }
                        else if($Loginmodel->validate() && $Loginmodel->login()) {

                            $this->redirect($this->base_url.'/congrats'); // Uncomment later
                            //self::actionSignupCongrats();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->setFlashError("Unable to register user, please try again");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $error_text = $response->getResponseText();
                    $error_code = $response->getResponseCode();
                    if ($error_code == 'E00003') {
                        $error_text = 'Credit card number is invalid';
                    }
                    // Add custom error messages
                    $model->addError('cardNumber', $error_text);
                }
            }
            else {
                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($model->errors); echo '</pre>';exit;
            }
        }

        $this->render('signup', array('model'=>$model, 'referrer_data' => $referrer_data, 'user_profile2' => $user_data));
    }
}
```

User model is

```
    <?php

if ( ! defined('YII_PATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CActiveRecord
{

    //variable to confirm passwords
    public $repeat_password;
    public $agree_terms;
    public $agree_referring_affiliate;
    public $agree_subscription;
    public $verifyCode;
    public $referrer;
    public $subid;
    public $token;
    public $cardNumber;
    public $cardCode;
    public $exp_year;
    public $exp_month;
    public $heard_about_us;
    public $agree_refund_policy;
    public $agree_subscription_cancel;


    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    public function beforeSave(){

        if(parent::beforeSave()){

            // for example
            if(!empty($this->password))
                $this->password = crypt($this->password, '$1$rasmusle$'); // if you save dates as INT

            //echo 'password: '.$this->password;exit;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }



    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs. 
        return array(
            array('first_name, last_name, email, phone_no, country, heard_about_us, state, city, zipcode, gender, username, password, registration_date, optin, role, cardNumber, cardCode, exp_year, exp_month', 'required', 'on' => 'signup'),
            array('first_name, last_name, email, phone_no, country,  state, city, zipcode ', 'required','on'=>'edit'),
            array('token', 'validateToken', 'on' => 'signup'),
            array('is_fb, optin, referrer', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('first_name, last_name, email, city, country', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            array('username', 'length', 'max'=>20),
            array('username', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^([a-zA-Z0-9_])+$/', 'message' => 'Username should be alphanumeric and can contain "_" only'),
            array('email', 'email'),
            array('email, username', 'unique', 'on' => 'signup'),   
            array('password, address', 'length', 'max'=>128),
            array('repeat_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>'Passwords don\'t match'),           
            array('zipcode', 'length', 'max'=>7),
            //array('image', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            //array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
            array('status', 'length', 'max'=>8),
            array('cardNumber', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('cardNumber', 'length', 'min'=>13),
            array('cardNumber', 'length', 'max'=>17),
            array('cardNumber', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^([0-9])+$/', 'message' => 'Credit Card Number should be numeric'),

            array('cardCode', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('cardCode', 'length', 'min'=>3),
            array('cardCode', 'length', 'max'=>4),
            array('cardCode', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^([0-9])+$/', 'message' => 'Security Code (CVV) should be numeric'),

            //array('exp_month', 'validateExpMonth', 'on' => 'signup'),

            array('fb_id', 'length', 'max'=>250),
            array('subid', 'unique'),
            array('role', 'length', 'max'=>11),
            array('last_login', 'safe'),

            //array('exp_month', 'ext.validators.CardDateValidator', 'compareValue' => 'exp_year', 'message' => 'failure message'),

            array('agree_refund_policy', 'required', 'message' => 'Please accept Karmora refund policy', 'on' => 'signup'),
            array('agree_subscription', 'required', 'message' => 'Please accept Karmora subscription terms', 'on' => 'signup'),
            array('agree_subscription_cancel', 'required', 'message' => 'Please accept Karmora subscription cancel terms', 'on' => 'signup'),
            //array('agree_referring_affiliate', 'required', 'message' => 'Please accept Karmora referring affiliate terms', 'on' => 'signup'), 

            // Old terms and conditions are changed in new signup page design.
            // array('agree_referring_affiliate', 'required', 'message' => 'Please accept Karmora referring affiliate terms', 'on' => 'signup'),
            // array('agree_terms', 'required', 'message' => 'Please accept Karmora terms and conditions', 'on' => 'signup'),
            // array('agree_subscription', 'required', 'message' => 'Please accept Karmora subscription terms', 'on' => 'signup'),

            // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
            //array('verifyCode','captcha','allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(), 'on' => 'signup'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, first_name, last_name, username, gender, heard_about_us, email, password, phone_no, registration_date, address, state, city, zipcode, country, image, status, last_login, is_fb, fb_id, optin, role', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'favouriteProducts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'FavouriteProducts', 'user_id'),
            'favouriteProducts1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'FavouriteProducts', 'user_id'),
            'favourites' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Favourites', 'user_id'),
            'reminders' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Reminder', 'user_id'),
            'traningMaterialPurchases' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TraningMaterialPurchase', 'user_id'),
            'userPayments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserPayments', 'user_id'),
            'usersCommissions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UsersCommission', 'user_referer'),
            'usersCommissions1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UsersCommission', 'user_referral'),
            'usersReferences' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UsersReferences', 'user_id'),
            'usersReferences1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UsersReferences', 'referer_id'),
            'usersTransactionsLogs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UsersTransactionsLog', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'phone_no' => 'Phone No',
            'registration_date' => 'Registration Date',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'state' => 'State',
            'city' => 'City',
            'zipcode' => 'Zipcode',
            'country' => 'Country',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'last_login' => 'Last Login',
            'is_fb' => 'Is Fb',
            'fb_id' => 'Fb',
            'optin' => 'Optin',
            'role' => 'Role',
            'heard_about_us'    =>  'Where You Heard About Us',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('first_name',$this->first_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('last_name',$this->last_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
        $criteria->compare('gender',$this->gender,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('phone_no',$this->phone_no,true);
        $criteria->compare('registration_date',$this->registration_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('address',$this->address,true);
        $criteria->compare('state',$this->state,true);
        $criteria->compare('city',$this->city,true);
        $criteria->compare('zipcode',$this->zipcode,true);
        $criteria->compare('country',$this->country,true);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
        $criteria->compare('last_login',$this->last_login,true);
        $criteria->compare('is_fb',$this->is_fb);
        $criteria->compare('fb_id',$this->fb_id,true);
        $criteria->compare('optin',$this->optin);
        $criteria->compare('role',$this->role,true);
        $criteria->compare('heard_about_us',$this->heard_about_us,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }


    /*
    public function CardDateValidator($attribute,$params){
        $cur_year = date('Y');

        if($this->compareValue == $cur_year){
                $cut_month = date('m');
        }

        if($cut_month){
            $js = '
                    if($.trim(value)<"' . $cut_month . '") {
                            messages.push("' . $this->message . '");
                    }
                ';
            return $js;
        }
    }*/

    public function validateToken($attribute,$params){

        $token = $this->token;
        if(!empty($token)){

            $command = yii::app()->db->createCommand();
            $admin_data = $command->select('*')
            ->from('fundraising_tokens')
            //->where('role:user_role', array(':user_role' => $user_role))
            ->where("token='". $token."' AND used_by <= 1" )
            ->queryRow();

            if(!$admin_data)
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid token number');
            else
                return true;


        }   

    }

    public function getUsersByRole($user_role){
        $command = yii::app()->db->createCommand();
        $admin_data = $command->select('*')
        ->from($this->tableName())
        //->where('role:user_role', array(':user_role' => $user_role))
        ->where("role='". $user_role."'")
        ->queryRow();

        if($admin_data)
            return $admin_data;
        else
            return false;       
    }

    public function getUsersByUserName($user_name){
        $command = yii::app()->db->createCommand();
        $admin_data = $command->select('*')
        ->from($this->tableName())
        //->where('role:user_role', array(':user_role' => $user_role))
        ->where("username='". $user_name."'")
        ->queryRow();

        if($admin_data)
            return $admin_data;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public function getUserIdByUsername($username){

        $detail = yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('u.id')
        ->from('users u')
        ->where('u.username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))
        ->queryAll();

        if($detail)
            return $detail[0];
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to get a dump from $_POST to check whether the heard_about_us has been sent or not?

Comment: yes it is present in `var_dump` of $_POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that attribute safe in model -> rules :

```
    public function rules() {
    return array(
    // other rules
    array('attribute_name_that_is_not_inserting', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

Comment: still not inserting it in db :(

Comment: Thanks so much . :)